# Conditional styles on a calculated value in Cognos

Tags: cognos-bi

I have a report (Pivot table) for which I have a value everyday. My goal is to calculate the variance every day and highlight with conditional styles.

| 1 jan. 23 | 2 jan. 23 | 3 jan. 23 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 25 | 42 |

I have a query who calculates the variance between days in % (which I dont want to put in the report).

My conditional style rule is `[Table].[Pourcentage variation D-1] between 0,05 and 10.`

Since my request is not in displayed my report, I have this error :

> RSV-VAL-0032 The following expression is not valid. If the item exists
> in a query but is not referenced in the layout, add it to a property
> list.

The problem is that I don't have the "Proprety list" in my pivot table like in can have in a Data table.

How can I highlight my variance based on a request that I dont display in my Pivot table ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try the following.  Add the calculated field to the pivot table (I know you do not want this in the layout, this is just to test if that removes the error).    See if the conditional style works the way you expect.  If so, change the column for the percentage data item to property, set box type to none.  This way it is still something that can be referred to, but is hidden from the final result

Comment: When I add the calculated field to the pivot table, my conditional style works well and I dont have any errors. Now I need to hide this percentage column from my report. How can I change the column for the percentage to property ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: Click on the field in the crosstab.  Go to you properties.  Find box type.  Set that to None.  You may have to do that for the heading and subtotals, just click on those parts too and set the box type to none

Answer (score 0):

Add the calculated field to the pivot table (I know you do not want this in the layout, this is just to test if that removes the error). See if the conditional style works the way you expect.

If so, change the column for the percentage data item to property, set box type to none. This way it is still something that can be referred to, but is hidden from the final result